# How to load a font in pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, fonts

The code I tried looks like this:

```
    var custom_font = new FontFace('myFont', 
       'url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=VT323&display=swap)');
    custom_font.load().then(function(loaded_face) {
       document.fonts.add(loaded_face);
       <etc>
    }
}).catch(function(error) {alert("Unable to load font!");});
```

}

The network download works just fine, but the console error message is:

```
Failed to decode downloaded font: https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=VT323&display=swap
```

There are similar questions, but in every case the answer involves doing something in HTML or CSS, and that option is not available. It has to be pure JS.

There is a WebFont library which is a possible fallback, but I really would rather get there in native code.

Comment: You are loading a CSS file as if it's a font, I don't think that's how thats supposed to work. That file you are referencing isn't really a 'standard font description' or something. You need to place a direct URL to a font _file_ itself there, according to the docs at MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FontFace/FontFace

Comment: Believe it of not, you just answered the question. Now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment, I put `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=VT323&display=swap` in the browser. It came back with:

```
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'VT323';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/vt323/v17/pxiKyp0ihIEF2isfFJU.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+0304, U+0308, U+0329, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
```

The string `url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/vt323/v17/pxiKyp0ihIEF2isfFJU.woff2)` is the answer to the question. Thanks!